# Xamarin forms - MVVM observable collection always 0 when getting values

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I have 2 observable collections, the idea is to load the Master Collection with all data from my database related to the form. I would filter this collection and use the filtered results to set Actor Collection. The reason im trying this is to reduce the time it takes to convert b64 image to ImageSource for larger collections. I like to convert these image only once

Onload of the form the Master Collection is populated with the items needed but when i click on a filter option, Master Collection is always 0. I can see onload 119 entries added to the collection

```
public ActorCollectionVM(INavigation navigation)
    {
        Navigation = navigation;
       
       // one time only populate
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
       {
           UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading");
           Database db = new Database();
           List<TMDB_Person> persons = db.GetAllPersons();

           ImageUtility util = new ImageUtility();

           foreach (TMDB_Person person in persons)
           {
               person.Profile_Thumb_Image = util.Base64ToImage(person.B64_Profile_Thumb_Image);
               MasterCollection.Add(person);
           }

           ActorCollection = MasterCollection;

           UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
       });

    }


 private void LetterSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ActorCollectionVM context = (ActorCollectionVM)BindingContext;
        context.ActorCollection.Clear();

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        btn.TextColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["ThemeColor"];

        if (btn.Text != "ALL")
        {
            foreach (TMDB_Person person in context.MasterCollection.Where(x => x.Name[0].ToString().ToLower() == btn.Text.ToLower()))
                context.ActorCollection.Add(person);            
        }
        else
        {
            context.ActorCollection = context.MasterCollection;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ActorCollection = MasterCollection;` - this replaces the collection reference, it does not copy the collection. `ObservableCollection` properties should be `get`-only and backed by a `readonly` field (so they cannot have their references replaced)

Comment: Generally speaking, **you should not perform IO in class constructors** (the biggest clue is the fact you can't use `async` methods in constructors). You should do it in a factory method instead.